# Receiving ERROR JWTValidatorImpl Error while parsing JWT java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, okta

I have a project that is using wso2 v4.1.0 API Manager and it is using Okta to authenticate users to my application. I have upgraded the wso2 from v3.2.0 to v4.1.0. Will provide more info if required

I'm hitting the following error in v4.1.0 but not in v3.2.0. They are both running on the same machine.

> [PassThroughMessageProcessor-148] ERROR JWTValidatorImpl Error while parsing JWT
> java.net.UnknownHostException: XXX.okta.com
> at java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[?:?]
> at java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:883) ~[?:?]
> at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1519) ~[?:?]
> at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1378) ~[?:?]
> at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1306) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient_4.5.13.wso2v1.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.JWTUtil.retrieveJWKSConfiguration_aroundBody0(JWTUtil.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.JWTUtil.retrieveJWKSConfiguration(JWTUtil.java:52) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.retrieveJWKSet_aroundBody22(JWTValidatorImpl.java:227) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.retrieveJWKSet(JWTValidatorImpl.java:224) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateSignature_aroundBody8(JWTValidatorImpl.java:145) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateSignature(JWTValidatorImpl.java:135) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateToken_aroundBody0(JWTValidatorImpl.java:62) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateToken(JWTValidatorImpl.java:57) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidationServiceImpl.validateJWTToken_aroundBody0(JWTValidationServiceImpl.java:44) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidationServiceImpl.validateJWTToken(JWTValidationServiceImpl.java:36) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.getJwtValidationInfo_aroundBody32(JWTValidator.java:691) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.getJwtValidationInfo(JWTValidator.java:659) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate_aroundBody0(JWTValidator.java:174) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate(JWTValidator.java:142) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate_aroundBody4(OAuthAuthenticator.java:301) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:111) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate_aroundBody56(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:522) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:516) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody46(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:402) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:353) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
> at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:403) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(AbstractApiHandler.java:107) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.identifyAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:127) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:59) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:90) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:76) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:101) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:376) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:190) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]

I have double checked the key store manager is set up correctly multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `java.net.UnknownHostException` which means the DNS/Hoatname(`XXX.okta.com`) you are trying to connect to is not resolvable.

By looking at the error it seems API Manager is trying to connect to the JWKS endpoint and this call is failing. Take a look at [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/access-token-types/jwt-tokens/#validating-jwts-generated-by-external-oauth-providers) and see whether you need to fix any configs around the JWKS configs.

Also, make sure `XXX.okta.com` is accessible from the APIM server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

hostname should be resolvable because v3.2.0 is installed in the same version and that version is working well. 

Not sure why when I moved to v4.1.0, suddenly it is not working anymore

Comment: @JasonSivan Probably 3.2 doesn't make this call. Did you verify the host is resolvable? Just SSH into the server and try to ping the host from within the server.

Comment: the server can ping/curl  to XX.okta.com through a proxy server. Does this impact APIM connecting to that as well?

Comment: @JasonSivan of course, everything that uses the network is affected. You may have to add proxy configurations to APIM in that case.

Comment: sorry missed out on this. how do i add proxy configurations to APIM? How is it different from wso v3.2.0?